# Dispose frame In Its Constructor

Tags: java, swing, constructor, jframe, dispose

I want to dispose a frame in its constructor when the condition is true.

`this.dispose` is not disposing frame. I want that, when my constructor is called, if condition i.e (`configurationBean.getCode().equals(macPass)`) is true then a new frame have to be called and this frame must have to be closed. Else this frame have to be created.

```
 public ConfigurationFrame() {
    String pcMac = getPcMacAddress();
    String macPass = getPassword(pcMac);
    ConfigurationDao configurationDao = new ConfigurationDaoImpl();
    ConfigurationBean configurationBean = configurationDao.checkCode(macPass);
    if(configurationBean == null)
        initComponents();
    else if(configurationBean.getCode().equals(macPass))
    {      
        new MainLoginFrame().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
        super.setVisible(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: A constructor is really not the right place for this.

Comment: This is a very bad design plan; simply don't do it

Comment: Ok. Then give me some suggestions.

Comment: Instead 1) **never** extend JFrame, and instead extend or use JPanels and create JFrames or other top-level windows where needed. 2) For a dialog window like this, use a *modal* JDialog and not a JFrame.

Comment: I want that when ever my program runs then it must check the condition if the condition is true then the new frame must be displaced and this frame have to be destroyed else the frame have to be created... Give some suggestions on this logic..

Comment: Please consider showing a small demo program of what you're trying to achieve, such as a [mcve]. Also explain some background -- what would make the condition true vs false? what are the purposes of the windows that you're trying to display?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your question is a classic "[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)" type question where you ask "how do I do X", when the best solution is "Don't do X but instead do Y". In other words you definitely do **not** want to dispose of a top-level window object such as a JFrame in its constructor as you're trying to do.

I think that what you want to do (a guess) is to

1. Test the configuration of things
2. If OK, display the main GUI
3. If not OK, then display a window that allows the user to re-set the configuration
4. Key point:  then re-test if the configuration is OK,
5. And if so, then display main GUI
6. Repeat as necessary.

If so, then I would use a while loop to show the set configuration window and exit the loop if the configuration is OK, but also allow the user to exit the loop if they simply want to quit or can't set the configuration OK.  Something like this:

```
// configurationGood: true if config is good
// justQuit: true if the user has had enough and wants to quit
while (!configurationGood && !justQuit) {
    // create configuration dialog here
    // calling constructors, and all
    // use a **modal** dialog here

    // change configurationGood and/or justQuit values in here
}

if (!justQuit) {
    // create and display main application here
}
```

Note that

- this code is not called within any GUI window constructor, but rather prior to displaying the GUI
- The re-set configuration window shouldn't be a JFrame but rather a *modal* JDialog
- This way the program code flow halts while the dialog is displayed and only resumes after the dialog has been dealt with.
- This allows the code within the while loop to query the dialog the state of its fields and use this to re-test that the configuration is OK

Comment: Your logic is going over my head... Although I have solved the problem myself... got help from a friend. Thanks for your kind response...

Comment: @Asmat: the logic is nothing but boolean checks. What confuses you specifically?